# Unstaged files lost after git reset --hard HEAD^ without having run git add - can I get them back?

Tags: git, git-reset

I did:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

I did not do:

```
git add .
```

before thus my work was only in my *working directory* and not on the branch *index*, are my changes lost? Can I get them back?

**Edit:**

All files were modified and had been tracked by `git` but were just not staged on *index*.

Comment: If they never were on the index, then no, you can't get the changes back, at least not with git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a file isn't tracked by git, it shouldn't be deleted by a hard reset (according to the help docs and I ran a test just to verify).

If an "unstaged" file has being tracked by git, the changes will be lost. At some point, likely 'git add X' was run, where X matched the file.

If the file is deleted, the only route I know if is to imediately stop editing and try an "undelete" utility.  The more changes you make to the harddisk, the less likely you will recover the data.

Comment: All files had been tracked by git, thus ... unrecoverable :'(